# Increase OverviewMap preview size with IIIF as a source

Tags: openlayers

I am using OpenLayers to display images from IIIF server and added and OverviewMap. However the issue I stumbled upon is that the OverviewMap image is too small. I'd like to set it over the entire overview map window (blue border in overview map on the image bellow, in CSS terms would be background-size: contain).

In the [OverviewMap](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overviewmap.html) docs I did not found any useful parameters. I also checked the [Layer](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Layer-Layer.html) and tried to set minZoom and the extent, but no luck.

I created a simple (and a bit dirty) demo [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/iiif-lq564?file=/index.html), which is a combination of the official `IIIF demo` and `custom OverviewMap` demos.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate and set the minZoom for the overviewmap which must be done after adding it to the main map so you have the overviewmap size.

```
var ovMap = overviewMapControl.getOverviewMap();
var maxRes = ol.extent.getWidth(iiifTileSource.getTileGrid().getExtent()) / ovMap.getSize()[0];
ovMap.getView().setMinZoom(ovMap.getView().getZoomForResolution(maxRes));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/iiif-wslw5